# How to ignore generated code from code coverage data

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and would like to exclude the generated service reference code from my code coverage statistics.

I found an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122043119/http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2008/11/10/hiding-generated-code-from-code-analysis-metrics-and-test-coverage.aspx) pre 2010 that mentions using DebuggerNonUserCode and DebuggerHidden attributes. I have tried this an it works as advertised. DebuggerNonUserCode is set at the class level, but with 50+ classes generated in each of the generated service reference code files, this is not an attractive option.

Does anyone have any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a code generator that emits partial classes with the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately the cost of creating the code generator, testing etc, outways the cost of adding this manually to the existing generated code. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 17):

The generated classes are partial. If you create a new class in your project with the same namespace and class declaration you can add the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute to your partial class. That way you don't have to go back and edit the `Reference.cs` file whenever you refresh your reference.

Answer (score 5):

In `Reference.cs`, you can find an existing attribute, like `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]` and do a search and replace with `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()][System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]`.
The major drawback is that you have to redo this each time you update the reference.

I don't understand why MS does not make the code coverage tool smart enough to skip service reference generated code.

Answer (score 3):

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984116.aspx#footerLink) can be used on top of the class. This is a poor option since you need to redo this anytime you regenerate your code. Maybe Microsoft could do this for us automagically when creating service references, entity framework types, etc...