# T4MVC messing with my coverage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4, t4mvc

We're using t4mvc in our project which requires min 85% coverage

since adding in t4mvc our coverage has bombed! I don't see the point in testing generated code - is there a way to ommit this stuff from our coverage?

we're  using xunit fwiw

Comment: Could you modify the templates to include the DebuggerNonUserCode attribute?  similar/duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337887/how-to-ignore-generated-code-from-code-coverage-data

Answer (score 3):

exactly as I was going to say G_P re your comment. the way to approach this is to add the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute, either at class level or at method level.

```
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
public partial class MyClass
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public string SomeMethod
    {

    }

    public bool Anothermethod
    {

    }
}
```

see also:

- http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2009/03/unit-testing-and-code-coverage-tip.html
- http://donovanbrown.com/post/I-dont-want-Entity-Framework-code-counted-in-code-coverage.aspx

should get you started...

Comment: T4MVC already adds DebuggerNonUserCode in most places, so I would think that should be enough!

Comment: ncover seems to be ignoring it.

Comment: it also seems to ignore the ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute!! arrrr

Comment: mayby David  (ebbo) as author might be able to step in and give guidence on that for you.. fingers xx'd